# Neo4J Cluster - Bolt + Routing

Tags: neo4j, routes, cluster-computing, bolt

[Neo4j Document](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/client-applications/) says we can use the ***bolt + routing*** when we are using the Cluster Mode/setup. I am able to use single node with bolt connection without any issue but if I use the cluster mode/setup it gives me the following error.

`Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: 'bolt+routing' is not a supported transport (in 'bolt+routing://username:password@server.com:7687', available transports are: [bolt].`

In cluster mode if I just use  
`bolt+routing://username:password@server.com:7687` 
 I am getting  NotALeader Error as below 
`config.Neo4jConfiguration: Intercepted exception
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher: Neo.ClientError.Cluster.NotALeader
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.commit(BoltTransaction.java:75)`

Note: I am using Spring Data Neo4j for my application

Comment: what is your driver version ?

Answer (score 3):

The document says, that "The address in the URI must be that of a core server."
You can set your cluster member to be a core with this configuration in neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.mode=CORE
```

And in browser you can check the member roles:

```
CALL dbms.cluster.role()
```

Answer (score 1):

The OGM bolt driver version (neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver) should be 2.1.0

Reference to [Spring SDN Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#_compatibility) helps to resolve the issue.